# Which year to consider in this date time format string in python?

Tags: python

In the Date time string  "Aug 18 00:00:38" what year does python 3 consider in this ? This is the postfix log of emails.

I want to convert to datetime string to store the value in postgres table.
Currently on conversion, it displays:

```
from  datetime import datetime
s = "Aug 18 00:00:38"
mdatetime = datetime.strptime(s,'%b %d %H:%M:%S')
datetime.datetime(1900, 8, 18, 0, 0, 38)
```

I am trying to store the postfix logs to postgres table by capturing datetime too. The logs begin as:

> Aug 18 00:00:29 smtp1 postfix....

Comment: It doesn't consider it as anything as long as you leave it as a string. What are you trying to do with that string?

Comment: This assign the value to a date time object and print it, you can see the year

Comment: If you care about the year, store it explicitly, with all 4 digits. The problem you encounter is quite similar to Y2K, the most expensive mistake in the history of computing. Don't store 2 digits assuming 20 means 2020. Lloyds had to close down for some days this year because the lazy Y2K fixes they implemented back in 2000 interpreted anything below a cutoff as a date in the 1900s, so 20 became 1920 - back in 2000 they probably had a *lot* of very rich customers with birthdates in the 1920s.

Comment: But there is no way to detect the postfix log year. We are assuming the log of the current year. Shall i assume that the postfix log has this bug then?

Answer (score 1):

If you use dateparser python library, you can get a year of 2020(this year).

```
import dateparser

st = "Aug 18 00:00:38"
print(dateparser.parse(st))
```